# arrayadapter error when created outside onCreate

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayAdapter that I use to fill a listview, but I'm unable to create it outside the oncreate event, but at that time I don't have the data.

```
public class CusPickup extends Activity {

private OrdersReady orderready_data[];
private ListView lView; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orders);
```

Here I will get a null point exception.

```
    OrderReadyAdapter adapter = new OrderReadyAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, orderready_data);
    lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    lView.addHeaderView(header);
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);

getData();
}
}
```

Here I get the data from HTTP get.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            String bundleResult = msg.getData().getString("RESPONSE");
                int TotalRecords = myResult.d.results.size();
                for (int i = x; i < TotalRecords; i++ ) {
                    orderready_data[i] = new OrdersReady(myResult.d.results.get(i).myStr, myDate ,invResult.d.results.get(i).numberStr, invResult.d.results.get(i).qtyInt, myAmount)
                }  
           }
}
```

If I place the OrderReadyAdapter her I get a code error with a fix "change OrderReadyAdapter(Context, Int, OrdersReady[]) to OrderReadyAdapter(Handle, Int, OrdersReady[]) if I change it I will get more errors.

Also I'm not sure if my declaration of the private OrdersReady orderready_data[] is correct, because if I declare it in code I would declare it like this: OrdersReady orderready_data[] = new OrdersReady[TotalRecords];

Thanks for any help.

---

New Adapter

```
public class OrderReadyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OrdersReady>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
ArrayList<OrdersReady> data = null;

public OrderReadyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<OrdersReady> orderReadyArray) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, orderReadyArray);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = orderReadyArray;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    OrderHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new OrderHolder();
        holder.mytxt1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mytxt1);
        holder.mytxt2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mytxt2);
        holder.mytxt3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mytxt3);
        holder.mytxt4 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mytxt4);
        holder.mytxt5 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mytxt5);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (OrderHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    OrdersReady orderready = data.get(position);
    holder.mytxt1.setText(orderready.place);
    holder.mytxt2.setText(orderready.Date);
    holder.mytxt3.setText(orderready.invoice);
    holder.mytxt4.setText(String.valueOf(orderready.Qty));
    holder.mytxt5.setText(String.valueOf(orderready.Amount));

    return row;
}

static class OrderHolder
{
    TextView mytxt1;
    TextView mytxt2;
    TextView mytxt3;
    TextView mytxt4;
    TextView mytxt5;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change the OrdersReady[] into ArrayList. Initialize it in your onCreate method. Also make the orderReady adapter into a class field.

```
orderReadyArray = new ArrayList<OrderReady>();
ordersReadyAdapter = new OrderReadyAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, orderReadyArray);
lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
lView.addHeaderView(header);
lView.setAdapter(ordersReadyAdapter);
```

This should initialize an empty listview as you don't have the data yet.

When you receive OrdersReady data from the server, update orderReadyArray as such:

```
orderReadyArray.clear(); // remove old data
for (int i = x; i < TotalRecords; i++ ) {
   orderReadyArray.add(data); // add new data one by one
}
ordersReadyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this forces the listview to repaint
```

Alternatively:

You can create a new adapter and assign it to the listview once you receive the data:

```
List<OrderReady> orderReadyArray = new ArrayList<OrderReady>(); // create a new array to hold data
for (int i = x; i < TotalRecords; i++ ) {
   orderReadyArray.add(data); // add new data one by one
}
OrderReadyAdapter ordersReadyAdapter = new OrderReadyAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, orderReadyArray);
lView.setAdapter(ordersReadyAdapter);
```

This should update your list. If you still do not see the items, the problem is in the adapter, perhaps you are inflating the row incorrectly in getView() method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I change the above question from the line down and I now have a problem with the adapter.

Comment: I must have changed the Adapter wrong because I'm unable to add(data) as (string,string,string, int, double) it now takes (int, OrderReady)

Comment: Change the line: OrdersReady orderready = data[position]; to OrdersReady orderready = data.get(position);

Comment: Thanks, I got it running, but nothing shows in the listview. When I run the debugger I see that orderReadyArray.add(data) is done three times. Here is how I add the data:   orderReadyArray.add( new OrdersReady(mydataStr, mydataStr ,mydataStr, mydataInt, mydataFloat)); after this I have this line: ordersReadyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I added Break Points in the adapter and I see i goes to the declaration of the adapter but it never goes to the inflater part of the adapter: @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) the inflate is in here.

Comment: Did you declare orderReadyArray as the field in the Activity, and pass it into the ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your questions. My activity starts like this: public class OrderPickup extends Activity { private ArrayList<OrdersReady> orderReadyArray;  The adapter I did just as you wrote in the Answer.

Comment: I added new way you can solve this. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I tried but I get the same error in the editor like before when I tried to add it outside the oncreate: OrderReadyAdapter ordersReadyAdapter = new OrderReadyAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, orderReadyArray);
The editors fix is to change the constructor of the OrdersReadyAdapter from (Context,Int,... to (Handle, Int, .. I add my OrdersReadyAdapter to my question above. Thanks again

Comment: The compilation error is easy to fix. Just use this: OrderReadyAdapter ordersReadyAdapter = new OrderReadyAdapter(CusPickup.this, R.layotu.listview_item_row, orderReadyArray); i.e. change 'this' to 'CusPickup.this'.

Comment: Still nothing. The getView never gets called. I added getCounts in the adapter and when I set it to Return 1 the getView was called and I was able to get one of the three records to show in the ListView. I added a orderReadyArray.size after it is loaded and the size returns 2, that should be 3 records. So for some reason it is not getting the count and therefore the getView is never called.

Comment: How about in the onCreate() method of your activity, create an OrderReadyAdapter of your array with a few test objects, then assign it to your listview, this should populate your listview, provided your Adapter is correct. If you don't get items in the listview, then your OrderReadyAdapter is not right, or you created it wrong.

Comment: So the Adapter could be wrong even if I can get it to display one record when I set getCount to return 1? I added the whole adapter above do you see any thing incorrect?

Comment: Your constructor in the adapter is wrong. You need to call super(context, layoutResourceId, orderReadyArray); This is because the base adapter also needs a reference to your array, for getCount() and getView() methods to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks that did it, I have been looking at that Adapter for days and hours and never noticed it was missing. Thanks again.